# How to find $\lim _{n\to \:\infty }P^n$ without calculating $P^n$?

Tags: markov-chains

Given the discrete time markov chain

P= $\begin{pmatrix}0.6&0.4&0&0\\ 0.2&0.8&0&0\\ 0&0&0.6&0.4\\ 0&0&0.4&0.6\end{pmatrix}$

How do I find $\lim _{n\to \:\infty }P^n$ without calculating $P^n$?

I know it has something to do with the fact that this markov chain is two isolated ergotic chains, but I don't know how to find the limiting distribution without finding $P^n$

Comment: The matrix $P$ is diagonalizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $P$ is block-diagonal you can indeed split this problem into subproblems that involve the individual $2\times2$ blocks. Now, there’s a theorem that the rows of powers of the transition matrix of an ergodic chain tend toward the stationary distribution as $n\to\infty$, so you just need to find the stochastic left eigenvector of $1$ for each of the $2\times2$ blocks. The column sums of the lower-right block are equal, so its stationary distribution is $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$. With a little bit of work you should be able to find the stationary distribution for the other block.

If you don’t happen to know this fundamental theorem, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538095/265466) you can decompose each block into the form $\lambda_1P_1+\lambda_2P_2$. Since $P_1^2=P_1$, $P_2^2=P_2$ and $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$, $(\lambda_1P_1+\lambda_2P_2)^n=\lambda_1^nP_1+\lambda_2^nP_2$. When $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lvert\lambda_2\rvert\lt1$, as is the case here, we therefore have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(P_1+\lambda_2P_2)^n=P_1$. Taking the lower-left block as before, examining the trace gives $\lambda_2=0.6+0.6-1=0.2$, and so $$P_1=\frac1{1-0.2}\begin{bmatrix}0.6-0.2 & 0.4 \\ 0.4 & 0.6-0.2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix},$$ which agrees with the eigenvector method used above. I’ll leave working out the other block to you.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues of this matrix are $1,0.4,1,0.2$ and you can find a matrix $U$ such that $$P=U^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&0.4&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0.2\end{pmatrix}U.$$

Then $P^n$ tends to $$U^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}U.$$