# Getting the matrix exponential of a 2x2 with eigenvalues with real and imaginary parts

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Struggling to simplify the matrix exponential of the following matrix:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a 
\end{pmatrix}$$
It's trivial to observe the eigenvalues are $a±bi$, but the algebra gets pretty involved if I can't figure out how to apply that knowledge. Is there a trick to simplify this exercise?

Comment: You have found the eigenvalues, cool. Can you find corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: a+bi has [i; 1] and the other has [-i; 1]

Comment: Cool. So can you diagonalize the matrix, then?

Comment: by T^-1 * A * T where T is [v_1 v_2], v_i are the eigenvectors? Yes

Comment: Yes. But since you're working with $A$ in the first place, it might be a better idea to write it the other way, as $A = TDT^{-1}$ instead, where $D$ is diagonal with eigenvalues as entries.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I could take $e^A = e^{TDT^-1} = Te^DT^{-1}$ ?

Comment: That's exactly what I am suggesting. It really is that easy (although you need a small argument by expanding the power series definition of $e^{TDT^{-1}}$ to show that it is indeed equal to $Te^DT^{-1}$). And taking exponentials of diagonal matrices are easy.

Comment: Yes. Diagonalisation is a good way to compute the matrix exponential.

Comment: I claim to know how to prove that. Thanks @Arthur!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel So it seems! But, perhaps just as interestingly, how many poor ways can you think of? Algebra for instance, seems ill suited, but possible, after juggling out matrix multiplications and power series

Comment: No need to diagonalize. See the complex eigenvalues case of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538095/265466).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $e^A=Pe^DP^{-1}$

where $D=diag(a+ib,a-ib)$ is diagonal matrix and $P$ is the matrix having the eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ as its columns. Needless to mention here that $e^D=diag(e^{a+ib}, e^{a-ib})$

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem as described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538095/265466), we set $$G=A-aI=\begin{bmatrix}0&-b\\b&0\end{bmatrix}$$ to obtain $$e^{at}\exp(tG) = e^{at}\left((\cos{bt}) I+\frac{\sin{bt}}b G\right) = \begin{bmatrix}e^{at}\cos{bt}&-e^{at}\sin{bt}\\e^{at}\sin{bt}&e^{at}\cos{bt}\end{bmatrix}.$$

If you note the isomorphism between matrices of the form in your question and complex numbers, you might even guess that this would be the solution from the corresponding identity $e^{t(a+ib)} = e^{at}(\cos{bt}+i\sin{bt})$.