# Find the general solution of the system $X'=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}X$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Find the general solution of $X'=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}X$

What I did: I calculated that the matrix has repeated eigenvalues of 0. When I plugged this in, I got that an eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$. So one solution of the system is $c_1\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ for a constant $c_1$. But I can't find another solution.

Comment: The repeated eigenvalue needs special treatment, [see here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedEigenvalues.aspx) - a link to Paul's Online Notes, should help you answer this question.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you!

Comment: There’s no need to ever compute eigenvectors, generalized or otherwise, to calculate the exponential of a $2\times2$ matrix. See the repeated eigenvalues case in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538095/265466).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is easier to solve directly, since the system reduces to $x' = y$ and $y' = 0$. I would say eigenvalues and so on would be overkill here.

Comment: Yes, I have got it now. I also got the same result using the method in the link @Gregory sent. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is quite clear that this equation is simple to solve without the method I linked to in comments, but it seemed that the OP was meant to get some familiarity with how solving that type of system would work.